# Dictionaries, adding more than one value with .get

Tags: python, dictionary

I need some advice here. I want to create a dictionary with soccer teams, the number of points they have and the number of matches they have played. Each list in analyzed contains a match, and the team with the most points wins and gets 3 points.. number of points to each team is calculated with the calculateScores function in line #4. However, I want to also keep track of how many games each team have played. **Can I do that with the .get statement?** My function returns `{'Steinkjer': 0, 'Byåsen': 6, 'Kvik Halden': 3}`, but I want it to return `{'Steinkjer': [0, 2], 'Byåsen': [6, 3], 'Kvik Halden': [3, 1]}`. Thanks in advance!

```
analyzed = [['Steinkjer', 'Byåsen', 3, 5], ['Byåsen', 'Steinkjer', 2, 1], ['Byåsen', 'Kvik Halden', 2, 10]]   

def sumTeamValues(analyzed):
    D = {}
    for match in analyzed:
       scores = calculateScores(match[-2],match[-1])
       D[match[0]] = D.get(match[0],0) + scores[0]
       D[match[1]] = D.get(match[1],0) + scores[1]
    return D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no way of doing it with only one get statement. Simply store the array in the dictionnary :

```
analyzed = [['Steinkjer', 'Byåsen', 3, 5], ['Byåsen', 'Steinkjer', 2, 1], ['Byåsen', 'Kvik Halden', 2, 10]]   

def sumTeamValues(analyzed):
    D = {}
    for match in analyzed:
       scores = calculateScores(match[-2],match[-1])
       D[match[0]] = [D.get(match[0],[0, 0])[0] + scores[0], D.get(match[0],[0, 0])[1] + 1]
       D[match[1]] = [D.get(match[1],[0, 0])[0] + scores[1], D.get(match[1],[0, 0])[1] + 1]
    return D
```

Comment: Thx, I tried replacing nb_games with 1(i.e. for every time the team plays, match increases with 1), but that didn't work. What is nb_games in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding to your dictionary manually, you can use a loop to add a new entry as it goes. I used `itertools.chain.from_iterable` and a `Counter` to get the game frequency per team and a list comprehension to get the winning team for each game. Then you can create a `defaultdict` instantiated with a list to sum the scores and append the game frequency. All the libraries are made available from Python's standard module library.

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

analyzed = [['Steinkjer', 'Byåsen', 3, 5], ['Byåsen', 'Steinkjer', 2, 1], ['Byåsen', 'Kvik Halden', 2, 10]]
freq = Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable([i[0:2] for i in analyzed]))
winners = [game[int(game[3] - game[2] > 0)] for game in analyzed]

d = defaultdict(list)

for team in winners:
    d[team].append(3)

for k,v in freq.items():
    d[k] = [sum(d[k])]
    d[k].append(v)
    print(f'team: {k}\ntotal points:{d[k][0]}\ntotal games:{d[k][1]}\n')

>>
team: Steinkjer
total points:0
total games:2

team: Byåsen
total points:6
total games:3

team: Kvik Halden
total points:3
total games:1
```

If say you have a draw scenario with

```
analyzed = [['Steinkjer', 'Byåsen', 5, 5], ['Byåsen', 'Steinkjer', 2, 1], ['Byåsen', 'Kvik Halden', 2, 10]]
```

You can change the parts above with the following, in the example, it adds 1 point to for a draw:

```
draws = []

for game in analyzed:
    if game[3] == game[2]:
        draws.append(game[0])
        draws.append(game[1])

d = defaultdict(list)

for team in draws:
    d[team].append(1)

for team in winners:
    d[team].append(3)

for k,v in freq.items():
    d[k] = [sum(d[k])]
    d[k].append(v)
    print(f'team: {k}\ntotal points:{d[k][0]}\ntotal games:{d[k][1]}\n')

>>
team: Steinkjer
total points:1
total games:2

team: Byåsen
total points:4
total games:3

team: Kvik Halden
total points:3
total games:1
```